# CMS GC works every 2 seconds without any reason

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection

I have small web server based on Spring. Sometimes I see that GC starts working hardly without any reason. Sometimes GC working for a long period, sometimes stops hardly working after few hours. Please help me to find out why GC works so hardly, why `GC (CMS Initial Mark)` happens?

Common info:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_60-b27), built on Aug  4 2015 12:19:40 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
Memory: 4k page, physical 14231888k(40224k free), swap 4194300k(3411224k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:+CITime -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:InitialHeapSize=268435456 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=268435456 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=314572800 -XX:MaxNewSize=178257920 -XX:NewSize=178257920 -XX:OldPLABSize=16 -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=./oom_happens.sh -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+PrintConcurrentLocks -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:-PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:SurvivorRatio=10 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC
```

Logs (server was working ok during 1.5 hours, then started `GC (CMS Initial Mark)` every 2 seconds)

```
2017-02-04T10:39:26.525+0200: 5.908: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-02-04T10:39:26.525+0200: 5.908: [ParNew: 145152K->14464K(159616K), 0.0265192 secs] 145152K->17461K(247680K), 0.0266811 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.02, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:26.553+0200: 5.936: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 2997K(88064K)] 19347K(247680K), 0.0029504 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:26.556+0200: 5.939: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-02-04T10:39:26.558+0200: 5.941: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.002/0.002 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:26.558+0200: 5.941: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T10:39:26.559+0200: 5.942: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:26.559+0200: 5.942: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 16350 K (159616 K)]2017-02-04T10:39:26.559+0200: 5.942: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0067469 secs]2017-02-04T10:39:26.566+0200: 5.949: [weak refs processing, 0.0001010 secs]2017-02-04T10:39:26.566+0200: 5.949: [class unloading, 0.0040362 secs]2017-02-04T10:39:26.570+0200: 5.953: [scrub symbol table, 0.0037057 secs]2017-02-04T10:39:26.574+0200: 5.957: [scrub string table, 0.0005995 secs][1 CMS-remark: 2997K(88064K)] 19347K(247680K), 0.0164263 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:26.576+0200: 5.959: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-02-04T10:39:26.576+0200: 5.959: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:26.576+0200: 5.959: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-02-04T10:39:26.577+0200: 5.960: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:29.153+0200: 8.536: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-02-04T10:39:29.153+0200: 8.536: [ParNew: 159616K->14463K(159616K), 0.1512181 secs] 162593K->29998K(247680K), 0.1513519 secs] [Times: user=0.51 sys=0.04, real=0.16 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:30.931+0200: 10.314: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-02-04T10:39:30.931+0200: 10.314: [ParNew: 159615K->11563K(159616K), 0.0257815 secs] 175150K->31143K(247680K), 0.0259213 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:30.957+0200: 10.340: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 19580K(88064K)] 33550K(247680K), 0.0024182 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:30.960+0200: 10.343: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-02-04T10:39:30.974+0200: 10.357: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.011/0.014 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:30.974+0200: 10.357: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T10:39:30.975+0200: 10.358: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:30.975+0200: 10.358: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T10:39:32.459+0200: 11.841: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 1.179/1.484 secs] [Times: user=5.31 sys=0.14, real=1.48 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:32.460+0200: 11.843: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 85694 K (159616 K)]2017-02-04T10:39:32.460+0200: 11.843: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0152197 secs]2017-02-04T10:39:32.475+0200: 11.858: [weak refs processing, 0.0001992 secs]2017-02-04T10:39:32.475+0200: 11.858: [class unloading, 0.0129920 secs]2017-02-04T10:39:32.488+0200: 11.871: [scrub symbol table, 0.0085933 secs]2017-02-04T10:39:32.497+0200: 11.880: [scrub string table, 0.0011467 secs][1 CMS-remark: 19580K(88064K)] 105275K(247680K), 0.0408012 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:32.501+0200: 11.884: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-02-04T10:39:32.510+0200: 11.893: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.009/0.009 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:32.511+0200: 11.893: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-02-04T10:39:32.511+0200: 11.894: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T10:39:53.578+0200: 32.961: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-02-04T10:39:53.578+0200: 32.961: [ParNew: 156715K->14464K(159616K), 0.0240020 secs] 169572K->39556K(247680K), 0.0241637 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:37:31.683+0200: 3491.066: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-02-04T11:37:31.700+0200: 3491.083: [ParNew (promotion failed): 159616K->159616K(159616K), 0.3959455 secs]2017-02-04T11:37:32.096+0200: 3491.479: [CMS: 85218K->80326K(88064K), 0.8836177 secs] 184708K->80326K(247680K), [Metaspace: 52323K->52323K(1095680K)], 1.3085194 secs] [Times: user=1.16 sys=0.16, real=1.31 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:37:32.992+0200: 3492.375: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 80326K(88064K)] 80930K(247680K), 0.0013563 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:37:32.994+0200: 3492.377: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-02-04T11:37:33.014+0200: 3492.397: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.019/0.020 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:37:33.014+0200: 3492.397: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T11:37:33.018+0200: 3492.401: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.003/0.004 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:37:33.018+0200: 3492.401: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2017-02-04T11:37:38.021+0200: 3497.404: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.047/5.002 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=5.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:37:38.021+0200: 3497.404: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 2415 K (159616 K)]2017-02-04T11:37:38.021+0200: 3497.404: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0021945 secs]2017-02-04T11:37:38.023+0200: 3497.406: [weak refs processing, 0.0002833 secs]2017-02-04T11:37:38.024+0200: 3497.407: [class unloading, 0.0153559 secs]2017-02-04T11:37:38.039+0200: 3497.422: [scrub symbol table, 0.0094751 secs]2017-02-04T11:37:38.049+0200: 3497.432: [scrub string table, 0.0012238 secs][1 CMS-remark: 80326K(88064K)] 82742K(247680K), 0.0295518 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:37:38.051+0200: 3497.434: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-02-04T11:37:38.116+0200: 3497.499: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.065/0.065 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.07 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:37:38.116+0200: 3497.499: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-02-04T11:37:38.117+0200: 3497.500: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:56:21.651+0200: 4621.034: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 38594K(88064K)] 88260K(247680K), 0.0199247 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.02, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:56:21.671+0200: 4621.054: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-02-04T11:56:21.690+0200: 4621.072: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.018/0.018 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.02, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:56:21.690+0200: 4621.073: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T11:56:21.692+0200: 4621.075: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.002/0.002 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:56:21.692+0200: 4621.075: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T11:56:21.692+0200: 4621.075: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:56:21.692+0200: 4621.075: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 49665 K (159616 K)]2017-02-04T11:56:21.692+0200: 4621.075: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0056309 secs]2017-02-04T11:56:21.698+0200: 4621.081: [weak refs processing, 0.0004105 secs]2017-02-04T11:56:21.699+0200: 4621.081: [class unloading, 0.0272522 secs]2017-02-04T11:56:21.726+0200: 4621.109: [scrub symbol table, 0.0170628 secs]2017-02-04T11:56:21.743+0200: 4621.126: [scrub string table, 0.0017874 secs][1 CMS-remark: 38594K(88064K)] 88260K(247680K), 0.0533350 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.01, real=0.06 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:56:21.746+0200: 4621.129: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-02-04T11:56:21.774+0200: 4621.157: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.028/0.028 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
2017-02-04T11:56:21.774+0200: 4621.157: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-02-04T11:56:21.774+0200: 4621.157: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:13.651+0200: 4913.034: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 25938K(88064K)] 88452K(247680K), 0.0116570 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:13.663+0200: 4913.046: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:13.684+0200: 4913.067: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.021/0.021 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:13.684+0200: 4913.067: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:13.686+0200: 4913.069: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.002/0.002 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:13.687+0200: 4913.069: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:13.687+0200: 4913.069: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:13.687+0200: 4913.070: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 62514 K (159616 K)]2017-02-04T12:01:13.687+0200: 4913.070: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0103963 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:13.698+0200: 4913.081: [weak refs processing, 0.0006922 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:13.698+0200: 4913.081: [class unloading, 0.0240702 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:13.722+0200: 4913.105: [scrub symbol table, 0.0147938 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:13.737+0200: 4913.120: [scrub string table, 0.0016158 secs][1 CMS-remark: 25938K(88064K)] 88452K(247680K), 0.0525941 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.02, real=0.05 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:13.740+0200: 4913.123: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:13.754+0200: 4913.137: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.014/0.014 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:13.754+0200: 4913.137: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:13.754+0200: 4913.137: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:15.754+0200: 4915.137: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 25872K(88064K)] 91296K(247680K), 0.0063790 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:15.761+0200: 4915.144: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:15.777+0200: 4915.160: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.016/0.016 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:15.777+0200: 4915.160: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:15.778+0200: 4915.161: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:15.778+0200: 4915.161: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:15.778+0200: 4915.161: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:15.779+0200: 4915.162: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 65423 K (159616 K)]2017-02-04T12:01:15.779+0200: 4915.162: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0060038 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:15.785+0200: 4915.168: [weak refs processing, 0.0002483 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:15.785+0200: 4915.168: [class unloading, 0.0122680 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:15.797+0200: 4915.180: [scrub symbol table, 0.0095177 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:15.807+0200: 4915.190: [scrub string table, 0.0012729 secs][1 CMS-remark: 25872K(88064K)] 91296K(247680K), 0.0303600 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:15.809+0200: 4915.192: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:15.820+0200: 4915.203: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.011/0.011 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:15.821+0200: 4915.203: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:15.821+0200: 4915.204: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:17.820+0200: 4917.203: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 25872K(88064K)] 91296K(247680K), 0.0072830 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:17.828+0200: 4917.211: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:17.844+0200: 4917.227: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.016/0.016 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:17.844+0200: 4917.227: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:17.845+0200: 4917.228: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:17.845+0200: 4917.228: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:17.845+0200: 4917.228: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:17.845+0200: 4917.228: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 65423 K (159616 K)]2017-02-04T12:01:17.845+0200: 4917.228: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0059133 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:17.851+0200: 4917.234: [weak refs processing, 0.0002355 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:17.852+0200: 4917.234: [class unloading, 0.0125640 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:17.864+0200: 4917.247: [scrub symbol table, 0.0092922 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:17.873+0200: 4917.256: [scrub string table, 0.0012690 secs][1 CMS-remark: 25872K(88064K)] 91296K(247680K), 0.0303227 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:17.876+0200: 4917.259: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:17.888+0200: 4917.271: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.012/0.012 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:17.888+0200: 4917.271: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:17.888+0200: 4917.271: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:19.888+0200: 4919.271: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 25872K(88064K)] 91543K(247680K), 0.0057390 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:19.894+0200: 4919.277: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:19.909+0200: 4919.292: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.016/0.016 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:19.909+0200: 4919.292: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:19.910+0200: 4919.293: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:19.910+0200: 4919.293: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:19.910+0200: 4919.293: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:19.911+0200: 4919.294: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 65670 K (159616 K)]2017-02-04T12:01:19.911+0200: 4919.294: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0060777 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:19.917+0200: 4919.300: [weak refs processing, 0.0002614 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:19.917+0200: 4919.300: [class unloading, 0.0122693 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:19.930+0200: 4919.312: [scrub symbol table, 0.0092923 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:19.939+0200: 4919.322: [scrub string table, 0.0012594 secs][1 CMS-remark: 25872K(88064K)] 91543K(247680K), 0.0302289 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:19.944+0200: 4919.327: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:19.954+0200: 4919.337: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.010/0.010 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:19.954+0200: 4919.337: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:19.954+0200: 4919.337: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:21.954+0200: 4921.337: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 25872K(88064K)] 91543K(247680K), 0.0058778 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:21.960+0200: 4921.343: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:21.976+0200: 4921.359: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.016/0.016 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:21.976+0200: 4921.359: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:21.977+0200: 4921.360: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:21.977+0200: 4921.360: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-02-04T12:01:21.977+0200: 4921.360: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2017-02-04T12:01:21.978+0200: 4921.361: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 65670 K (159616 K)]2017-02-04T12:01:21.978+0200: 4921.361: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0060719 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:21.984+0200: 4921.367: [weak refs processing, 0.0002574 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:21.984+0200: 4921.367: [class unloading, 0.0128628 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:21.997+0200: 4921.380: [scrub symbol table, 0.0106592 secs]2017-02-04T12:01:22.008+0200: 4921.391: [scrub string table, 0.0012721 secs][1 CMS-remark: 25872K(88064K)] 91543K(247680K), 0.0322165 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
```

P.S. Yes, I see that there are several `GC (Allocation Failure)`, and I understand why it happened. But I don't understand why there are `GC (CMS Initial Mark)` every 2 seconds:

```
2017-02-04T12:01:13.651+0200: 4913.034: [GC (CMS Initial Mark)
2017-02-04T12:01:15.754+0200: 4915.137: [GC (CMS Initial Mark)
2017-02-04T12:01:17.820+0200: 4917.203: [GC (CMS Initial Mark)
2017-02-04T12:01:19.888+0200: 4919.271: [GC (CMS Initial Mark)
2017-02-04T12:01:21.954+0200: 4921.337: [GC (CMS Initial Mark)
```

And so one during hours.

Comment: GC (CMS Initial Mark) is initial Marking phase of CMS where all the objects directly reachable from roots are marked.

Comment: I don't know why it happened. 

In result we increased space for Old Gen and **it helped**. We didn't change total heap memory, we decreased Young Gen space.

Probably CMS GC thougt that Old Gen wasn't enouph and tried to free some space there (marked objects to find candidates for deletion without success).